# Can I use Content Search with Glass to query children of a specific template?

Tags: content-search, glass-mapper

My Sitecore Item has children of different Templates.

To query them, I use the following field declaration:

```
[SitecoreQuery("*[@@templateid = '{ID of my Template}']", 
InferType = true, IsRelative = true, IsLazy = false)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<MyItemType> MyItemName{ get; set; }
```

Is there a more efficient way to retrieve them without having to use Sitecore Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have them in one list and just get the ones you want when you check the list?

```
[SitecoreType]
public class MyItemBaseType {
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

[SitecoreType]
public class MyItemType1 {
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string MyItemType1Property { get; set; }
}

[SitecoreType]
public class MyItemType2 {
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string MyItemType2Property { get; set; }
}
```

```
[SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]
public virtual IEnumerable<MyItemBaseType> MyItems { get; set; }
```

Then you could access them like so:

```
var theItem = getitem();

IEnumerable<MyItemType1> type1s = theItem.OfType<MyItemType1>();
string basePropertyValue = type1s.First().BaseProperty;
string type1PropertyValue = type1s.First().MyItemType1Property;

IEnumerable<MyItemType2> type2s = theItem.OfType<MyItemType2>();
basePropertyValue = type2s.First().BaseProperty;
string type2PropertyValue = type2s.First().MyItemType2Property;
```

Comment: So, the reason this works is that .OfType<T> is cheaper than the Sitecore Query?

Comment: Sort of. The difference is that when I call `OfType<T>()` above, all the items have already been loaded into memory, so it's doing a simple .NET type check. If you create multiple lists with different types in them, you are executing multiple queries to the database (one for each type) to get the contents of those lists.